# Is it Possible to Change Action For UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, action

I am trying to change Action For the UIButton in ios applicatio. I did Following Code

```
 button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethodShow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

    [view addSubview:button];
```

In particular Section I want to change Action for this Button .So i did this

```
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethodHide:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Hide View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Unfortunately This code  note Working?

Comment: aMethodShow is working for the first time? aMethodHide is not working when you change it?

Comment: two actions are taking same event(click)for the button , how can i remove first target.

Comment: You mean to say, when you click, both the methods are getting invoked?

Comment: have you tried - (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;

Comment: I tried , Both method invode for the Same Event .

Comment: Why this Action invoked?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest before adding new target, first invoke `removeTarget` on `UIbutton` object then add new target with other action.

Comment: Its Working Fine,Why this Action Invoked for same event

Answer (score 12):

I think it will help you

```
[yourButton removeTarget:nil 
               action:NULL 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents]; 

[yourButton addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(yourAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use same action target instead of using two target. In one target you have to differentiate like below

```
-(void)btnAction
{
        if(target1)
          {
            // code for target 1
          }

        else
         {
          // code for target 2
         }

}
```

Here target1 is `BOOL` value which value first set to be `YES`. And change its value `NO` whenever you want to perform target 2 code.

I hope this will helps You.

Comment: If i don't want to check the condition,if i am setting target more than one time with different selector(showButton,HideButton,etc) All action invoked simultaniously.. why this happent?

Answer (score 0):

I made an app recently and i had the same situation, but i found another way to solve it so i decided to share my solution with people who may be in the same situation.

I'll try to explain what i did with the context of this question:

- I added a tag to the `button` and i associated it with one of the functions that `button` needs to call (`aMethodShow:` for example).
- `button` always call the same function (`callSpecificFunc:` for example). What `callSpecificFunc:` does is call either function `aMethodShow:` or `aMethodHide` according with the current `button` tag.
- In the particular section in which the `button` needs to call a different function, i only change the tag of `button`.

Something like this:

```
NSInteger tagOne = 1000; //tag associated with 'aMethodShow' func
NSInteger tagTwo = 1001; //tag associated with 'aMethodHide' func

button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(callSpecificFunc:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];

...
// in some part of code, if we want to call 'aMethodShow' function,
// we set the button's tag like this
button.tag = tagOne

...

//Now, if we want to call 'aMethodHide', just change the button's tag
button.tag = tagTwo

...

-(void) callSpecificFunc:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSInteger tagOne = 1000;
    NSInteger tagTwo = 1001;

    if([sender tag] == tagOne){ 
        //do whatever 'aMethodShow' does
    }else {
        //do whatever 'aMethodHide' does
    }
}
```

Of course it could be applied for more than 2 functions :)